# \usepackage{newunicodechar} loads but commands have no effect

Tags: symbols, unicode, newunicodechar

Trying to use plaintext Unicode (UTF-8-encoded) symbols in a LaTeX source code. Made own definitions of the symbols in question, ASCII-only, just to prove the concept.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[verbose]{newunicodechar}
%⋮
 % Unicode
\newunicodechar{♢}{<>}
\newunicodechar{⧫}{!}
\newunicodechar{⬠}{(P)}
%⋮
\begin{document}
%⋮
\subsection{Introduction}
♢ ⧫ ⬠ 
%…
\end{document}
```

The compilation fails miserably as there were not any \newunicodechar:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2015.4.1)  10 JUL 2017 16:47  
entering extended mode  
 restricted \write18 enabled.  
 %&-line parsing enabled.  
**PP5_tiling.tex  
(./PP5_tiling.tex  
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>  
⋮  
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newunicodechar/newunicodechar.sty  
Package: newunicodechar 2012/11/12 v1.1 Defining Unicode characters  
)  
⋮  
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  not set up for use with LaTeX.  

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.  
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  
 ...                                              

l.63 ♢   
      ⧫ ⬠  
?
```

What may Ī̲ do wrong?

Comment: Why do you make testing your code more difficult by adding all this dots (and not adding \end{document})?

Comment: There are U+202F (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm) between your symbols.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: thanks, replacement of these solved the problem. Should  Ī̲ delete the question now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char   (U+202F)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

and U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE is nowhere defined.

If I add a declaration for it, there is no issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[verbose]{newunicodechar}
%⋮
 % Unicode
\newunicodechar{♢}{<>}
\newunicodechar{⧫}{!}
\newunicodechar{⬠}{(P)}
\newunicodechar{ }{\nolinebreak\hspace{.1em}}
%⋮
\begin{document}
%⋮
\subsection{Introduction}
♢ ⧫ ⬠ 
%…
\end{document}
```

Note the T1 encoding, or you'd not get `<` and `>`.

[image]

Why do you get a different error message? Because you're using a three year old TeX distribution. It's time to update.